# Custom projection function for mongodb aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I would like to have a custom projection function by supplying a javascript code that receives an object and returns a key just like in the case with the standart `group` operation.

Just an example, I would like to count browser's User-Agent strings, by platform. To get the platform, all I need is to count them by match. For example, `/Android/` vs `/iPad/` vs `/iPhone/` (each counted separately).

Is it somehow supported in mongodb nowadays? If not, is there any specific feature request I could vote for?

**Update:** A feature request was created: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9156.

Comment: No, it doesn't support that. Does the functionality of $group (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/group/) basically do what you want? (It doesn't work in a sharded system though). As to whether it's a specific request -- if you can't find it by searching, add it and add a link here, as it sounds like it might be interesting. :)

Comment: Nope, I've harshed through the page you've sent multiple times. It looks like I'll need to open a feature request.

Comment: This seems like a use-case for [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/) to me.

Comment: sure, however the framework is way neater to use, and faster